# Ubuntu Software update Problem

Tags: updates

```
W:Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/i18n/Index  
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This is not a ppa.

Comment: We need more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these commands on terminal,

```
sudo rm -Rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```