# update not happening sudo apt-get update command

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

Followings are the error output:

```
**W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead**.
```

---

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted #Added by enableDisableDistribution
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted #Added by enableDisableDistribution
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe #Added by enableDisableDistribution
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe #Added by enableDisableDistribution
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse #Added by enableDisableDistribution
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse #Added by enableDisableDistribution
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main #Added by enableDisableDistribution
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main #Added by enableDisableDistribution
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted #Added by enableDisableDistribution
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted #Added by enableDisableDistribution
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe #Added by enableDisableDistribution
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe #Added by enableDisableDistribution
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse #Added by enableDisableDistribution
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse #Added by enableDisableDistribution
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main #Added by enableDisableDistribution
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main #Added by enableDisableDistribution
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed universe restricted main multiverse
```

Comment: See if this is helpful.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/738160/apt-sudo-apt-get-update-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu Software update Problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/384793/ubuntu-software-update-problem)

Comment: Above mentioned both solutions are not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no `trusty-security` or `trusty-updates` entry for the extras repository.

If you go to http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ in your web browser, you will see that trusty-security and trusty-updates are not listed.

Run the following commands to fix the issue:

```
sudo sed -i 's|deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security|#deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security|g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo sed -i 's|deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates|#deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates|g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo sed -i 's|deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security|#deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security|g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo sed -i 's|deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates|#deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates|g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

You should inform "enableDisableDistribution" of this mistake or file a bug with them.

Comment: how to set this? Any pointer.  P.S:- Internet is working fine on this system. Also backup process is working fine. Facing this issue only with update

Comment: i did dis mentioned below but NO HELP  Open /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file.

sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
Comment out following line

dns=dnsmasq

Comment: I have checked All Settings>> Network Proxy>>  Method>> None

Comment: tried 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 but not working :(

Comment: @user561810 My bad, I see the problem. There should be no entry for trusty-security and trusty-updates for the "extras" repository. Please post the output of the following command in your question. `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` To post as code, after you paste the code in, highlight the code and then press CTRL+K and it will format as code for your question automatically. Then save the changes.

Comment: pasted the required info. please suggest

Comment: @user561810 Thank you. I have updated the answer.

Comment: out of 4-5 errors only this one is remaining Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]  ..please check this one too...deeply appreciating your quick help !!

Comment: @user561810 I have updated the post. This should fix the remaining errors.

Comment: @user561810 Glad to help. Don't forget to click the icon to the left to mark this as the accepted answer to your question. Thanks.